# Cleanest way to assign with short circuit evaluation on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I am trying to build a JSON object based on data that the client has on hand.

Ideally, it would select address data if available, then cart data if not available, otherwise null.

Here the data is retrieved from localStorage, but I run into issues, `addresses` and `cart` resolve the following errors when `null`.

> Cannot read property 'length' of null
>
> Cannot read property 'idShipTo' of undefined

```
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopping-cart'));
let addresses = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customer-address'));

this.request = {
  address: {
    shipToAddLine: addresses[0].shipToAddLine || cart.shipToAddLine || null,
    shipToCityStZip: addresses[0].shipToCityStZip || cart.shipToCityStZip || null
  }
}
```

I'd like to use something like the ternary operator, but use more than one if / else value.

```
this.request = {
  address: {
    shipToAddLine: (addresses) ? addresses[0].shipToAddLine || (cart) ? cart.shipToAddLine || null,
    shipToCityStZip: (addresses) ? addresses[0].shipToCityStZip || (cart) ? cart.shipToCityStZip || null
  }
}
```

Is this possible using a clean (one-line) syntax in JS, or do I have to put the assignments in if / else  blocks?

```
let shipToAddLine;
if (addresses) shipToAddLine = addresses[0].shipToAddLine;
else if (cart) shipToAddLine = cart.shipToCityStZip;
else shipToAddLine = null;
```

etc...

Comment: let something = (address instanceof Array) ? address[0].property : null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain ternary operators

```
    shipToAddLine: addresses ? addresses[0].shipToAddLine : (cart ? cart.shipToAddLine : null),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use initialize it to appropriate empty values if not present

```js
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopping-cart')) || {};
let addresses = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customer-address')) || [{}];

this.request = {
  address: {
    shipToAddLine: addresses[0].shipToAddLine || cart.shipToAddLine || null,
    shipToCityStZip: addresses[0].shipToCityStZip || cart.shipToCityStZip || null
  }
}
```

If cart is null, it is initialized to an empty object and if address is null initially it is initialized to an array having an empty object. Then you will not need checks before `addresses[0].shipToAddLine` and `cart.shipToAddLine`